# In google drive API, is there a way to find all the image files in multiple folders?

Tags: google-drive-api

In google drive API, is there a way to find all the image files in multiple folders?
I used 'mimeType' and 'in parents' with 'or' in my query (q).
However it does not work.
mimeType checking is working fine; however, if I put more than one 'in parents' grouping with 'or', it does not return any files.
I was trying to do something like this:
q would be like ('folderid' in parents or 'filderid2' in parents) and (mimeType = 'image/').
I might have mistyped (mimeType = ...) part here, but this part is working fine in my code. I just need to check 'folderid' in parents... part.
Thank you!

Comment: The query `('PARENT_ID_1' in parents or 'PARENT_ID_2' in parents) and mimeType = 'FILE_MIME_TYPE'` is working fine for me. Can you please check whether you are actually using this exact query, and that the id's and mime type are correct?

Comment: Strange, I also put the round bracket around the mimeType = xxx, so it would be like ('PARENT_ID_1' in parents or 'PARENT_ID_2' in parents) and (mimeType = 'FILE_MIME_TYPE'). But, it does not go into every parent folder specified by ids to search for the specific file's mime type which is specified mimeType. Is this working on your side? Which language did you use and could it be possible to share some portion of the code? I was using PHP. Thank!

Comment: I just used [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list). If you set just 1 parent folder, does it work correctly? Also consider providing the exact code you are using, maybe there's a typo there.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm facing the same problem. Both in node.js and my API client it fails to load any results (no errors) as soon as I put in more than one parent folder ID. Interestingly, I used Google's Try It Now API and it works just fine. Even looking at Try It Now request, it's exactly the same as my API client request. I even took my API client's query and used it in the Try It Now and it only works there, not in my API client.